# Are there any examples of replacing Azure Stream Analytics by Azure Functions for distributing data coming from IoT hub into SQL db?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-stream-analytics

Are there any examples of replacing Azure Stream Analytics by Azure Functions for distributing data coming from IoT hub into Azure SQL database?

According to the question raised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49076631/azure-functions-vs-azure-stream-analytics) and answers to it I can replace Azure Stream Analytics by Azure Function. My current architecture is as follows: `IoT edge devices > IoT hub > Stream Analytics > SQL database`. Due to the cost of Stream Analytics I would like to replace Stream Analytics.

My Stream Analytics job gets a JSON messages from IoT hub and distributes them into tables of Azure SQL database. To distribute the data the query in the SA job is utilized.

I would thanksfull to get at least hints to the resources on how I should replace SA (it is better to do it in python, but C# is ok as well).

Comment: hope this reference [helps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-store-data-sql-server?view=iotedge-1.4)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an Azure IoT Hub [resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-create-through-portal#create-an-iot-hub).
2. Create an Azure Function with an Event Hub binding to the default endpoint of [IoT Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-iot-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process%2Cnodejs-v4%2Cfunctionsv2%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp#example).
3. Add the SQL connection string to the application settings of the [Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings#settings).
4. Write c# code for SQL [database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-store-data-sql-server?view=iotedge-1.4).

The Another method is to stream using Azure Stream Analytics integration with Azure SQL [Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/stream-data-stream-analytics-integration?view=azuresql).

[image]

- For more details, refer to this [MSDOC](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sql/build-your-full-paas-iot-solution-with-azure-sql-database/).